# ERROR PHP: Unexpected Class but cant find the error

Tags: php, oop, command-line

**I know this question is asked many many times, but i cant find the right solution...**
This is only 1 file, there is a total of 3 files, and used to become a bowling scoring system.

It keeps saying this error on line 3 `class ScoreBoard` when using the code: "Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS"

```
<?php
​
class ScoreBoard {
​
    private $scores = [];
    private $players = [];
​
    public function __construct($players)
    {
        $this->players = $players;
    }
​
    public function calculatePlayerScore($player)
    {
        $this->scores[] = [$player];
    }
​
    public function calculateAllscores()
    {
        return $this->players;
    }
​
    public function displayscore()
    {
        return $this->scores;
    }
    
    public function displaywinner() {
      $this->calculateAllscores();
      $this->displayscore();
    }  
}
class Player
{
    private $name;
    private $pinsThrown = [];
​
    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
​
    public function throwPins($one, $two)
    {
        $this->pinsThrown[] = [$one , $two];
    }
​
    public function getPinsThrown()
    {
        return $this->pinsThrown;
    }
​
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }
}
​
?>
```

If someone knows, the right solution to fix this code. I would highly apreciate it!

Comment: Update this line of code `$this->players[] = $players;` and then try. Check is it resolving issues? And it may be `$player` not `$players`

Comment: Is this really the beginning of the script?

Comment: @MainulHasan Still giving the same error, sadly

Comment: @Barmar Im fully researching the code, but i really cant find itt..

Comment: @MainulHasan Why would that cause a syntax error? And if `$players` is an array, you wouldn't want to use `[]` there.

Comment: @Jean there are a hidden chars in your file.

Comment: @hassan How can i delete them then or is it wrong, sorry but i have never heard of, hidden chars.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, you are right. It seems he is not using the right, and that's why to get him to notice this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a hidden chars in your code. Not sure why and how does they are there. maybe saving the file without BOM will save your problem.

but previewing your file with a IDE ( sublime text in my case ) will clearly show your these encoded chars

[image]

Comment: Mate, it still doesnt work. I still think its a error in the code somewhere....

Comment: @Jean your code is totally right - I mean in the syntax - , HYG the result after removing the hidden chars https://3v4l.org/ItAOB